# Why using pointers (with low optimization) makes the program faster?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, embedded, iar

I was following a tutorial on embedded C programming, then realized that using a pointer to point to variable, then using it to dereference makes the program faster!

I've a basic knowledge of assembly, but I didn't figure why assigning the address of a variable to pointer would it make faster, we are not talking about pass by reference or by pointer or by value!

As I can follow,

- code without pointer: the memory address has been assigned to register `R0`, 
  like exactly what happened in the code with the pointer.
- the `p_int` became an alias to the register `R0`, how this can help making the program faster?

the code without using a pointer:

```
int counter = 0;
int main() {
    while (counter < 6) {
        ++(counter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then the assembly would be like in [image]

Conversely, here is the code with a pointer:

```
int counter = 0;
int main() {
    int *p;
    p = &counter;
    while (*p < 6) {
        ++(*p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then the assembly would be like in [image]

---

### **Update**

I reached out with the course creator and he was kind to replay and break it down for me, for the sake of help for others who may have encountered the same problem, I'll leave the question and the Answer

> To access a variable in memory, the CPU needs the address  of this
>   variable in one of the registers. At the lowest levels of code
>   optimization, the compiler  loads this address from the code memory
>   before each and  every access to the variable.  The pointer speeds
>   this up, because being a local variable inside the main() function is
>   allocated to a register.  This means that the address sits in a
>   register (R0 in this case)  and does not need to be loaded and
>   re-loaded into a register each time.  At higher levels of optimization
>   the compiler generates a more sensible code  and the code without the
>   pointer is as fast as with the pointer. --MMS

Comment: What compiler?  What level of optimization did you use?

Comment: the first one you ment to write while(counter < 6) right?

Comment: using IAR Worbench it's a compiler and deugger
level of optimization is low

Comment: yes Bwebb I meant (counter<6) as there is now pointer in this piece

Comment: What made you "realize" it was faster? How did you measure it? Moreover without applying compiler optimisation, the result is largely irrelevant since if performance were critical you'd use optimisation.  Unoptimised code favours debug experience over performance.

Comment: Avoid using off-site images, especially ones likely to be temporary in personal cloud storage. And don't post images of _text_ as you have done here.

Comment: @Clifford I need more than 15 reputation to be able to post images, as for what me realize that: in the assembly code there is a whole Instruction LDR.N is reduced when using pointer,

Comment: Benchmarking debug-mode code is pointless.  Enable optimization before benchmarking it or looking at it.  Anyway, copy/paste the asm output to make this a proper [mcve] if you're still wondering about the details of why one inefficient asm loop is after than another inefficient asm loop.  (And on what hardware?)

Comment: There is only one way to save this question: You need to edit it and tell *exactly* what you're doing for which processor and using which tools *and* the edit you did should be an **answer** to the question.

Comment: @AhmadMagrabi yes, but the dissassembly code is _text_, you need not have posted a screenshot in the first place. Moreover the first screenshot occludes part of the disassembly so that it is not possible to determine the target if the branch instructions

Comment: Your update should be posted as an answer rather then an edit to the question.  You are allowed to answer and accept answers to your own question.

Comment: I wonder if the result differs if `counter` were a local variable?  It is both unnecessary and poor practice to declare it outside of `main()` in this case.

Comment: thanks for the tips @Clifford, Mr. chqrlie updated it in the best way possible,
if counter was local to main there would be no difference,
the assembly starts from LDR.N in both images, that was my first question I would use these tips for sure :)

Comment: @Clifford, if local then it would be optimized out.   But based on the edit, this does seem like a simple case of the code needed to access a global variable makes for more instructions per loop.  would be easier to read if the code had just been pasted into the question rather than images.

Comment: You may want to check the tutorial [Embedded Programming  Lesson 3  Variables and Pointers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9WpXYBqdPU&t=148s)

Comment: @old_timer It was a rhetorical question. The point being to worry about the compiler performance for good code rather than bad.  In this case the code is not optimised, but nonetheless a register might be used - I would not regard that as "optimised out".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general: there is no reason why using pointers would make the program run faster. Discussing performance of programs without all optimizations enabled, like the course creator did in your quote, is not meaningful. It is certainly not a reason to change the way you write code.

Another old, often used but obsolete trick, is to write such loops as down-counting instead of up-counting, since compares against zero are often faster than compares against values. But this is also something you should not let affect the way you write code, because a modern compiler can do that optimization for you.

What programmers should do, and what people writing courses should teach, is to write the code as plain and readable as possible. Meaning that both your examples are bad, since they are needlessly obscure and examples of "pre-mature optimization". Better code would be:

```
  int counter;
  ...
  for(counter=0; counter < 6; counter++)
  {}
```

This is about as readable as code gets and there is no reason to believe that the above would perform worse than your examples on any known system.

Do this:

- Write the most readable code you can.
- In release, enable optimizations.
- If there are performance problems, benchmark and find bottlenecks.
- Manually optimize the bottlenecks if needed. Possibly with a specific system in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Any behaviour of the compiler that varies between optimisation levels is *implementation specific*. So although you have been shown something which is maybe rather counterintuitive as a demonstration, you should not have been taught that this is a causal relationship.

Writing code in a different way can *always* trigger performance improvements or regressions, and the different optimisation levels can *sometimes* result in changes that go the wrong way. It should be obvious, but any scenario where a higher optimisation level results on worse performance (not the case with this example) should be regarded as a problem for the compiler.

Comment: I think my previous title edit was confusing.  Both the OP's cases have optimization disabled, but introducing extra pointer variables actually helps instead of hurts like extra variables normally do, because ARM can't directly access static storage anyway; it has to construct a pointer in a register pretty similarly to using a local pointer variable.  I re-edited the title to avoid sounding like enabling optimization made it slower.

Comment: @PeterCordes, does 'optimisation disabled' actually have a formal meaning that can be extended to assuming that the lecturer's example will still behave in the same way in 10 years time? What I was trying to get at here is that the example doesn't support what seems to being taught. If what is being taught is that this 'leading the compiler in O0' is viable, that actually starts to sound misleading.

Comment: My understanding of "optimization disabled" is that each C statement is compiled to a separate block of asm, with all variables in memory between statements, nothing live in registers except stack and frame pointers.  (So vars can be modified by a debugger).  Within a single statement, the level of braindeadness varies wildly, e.g. GCC will still optimize `x / 10` into a multiplicative inverse.  (Fun fact: `register int foo;` actually will stay live in a register with gcc; the `register` keyword actually does something at `-O0`, unlike other times.) But fair point, IDK if everyone agrees on it

Comment: I didn't think the question was saying anything was being specifically *taught* as something you should remember.  At least I hope not, for the reasons you point out!  The OP says they noticed ("realized") the perf diff and asked the author of a tutorial about it.  (I think implying that it wasn't something the tutorial brought up).  So the "update" section was just an explanation of that curious behaviour in *this* specific case for this compiler for this ISA, since the OP asked specifically about it.

Comment: Tuning C source to optimize for `-O0` is silly, but wondering about performance differences in different asm versions of a function can be interesting, ignoring the fact that they both come from compiler output.  I've answered several x86 questions like that.  So this question is poorly worded, focusing on the C differences not the asm differences.

Comment: For example, I had auto-inlining break one of my integration tests (I think with -O0), and I assume it was working several years ago.

Comment: BTW, I just noticed that the code in the question *doesn't* have optimization fully disabled, not like `gcc -O0`.  I retitled it again >.<.  The `++counter` version only loads the var's address once for both accesses, but it's inside the loop right before the first use.  And the pointer version *does* keep the pointer value in a register throughout the function, not reloading it from the stack.  So the difference is just failure to do the `ldr` before jumping into the loop.  Even more of a special-case than you were suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

The original **Update** provides a good answer. Furthermore, in the original, "counter" is a global variable, so each access on the ARM chip requires loading the variable into a register first. Depending on where the variable is located, and the optimization level, this is at least one LDR instruction (could be more), then the update counter++ requires the add instruction and the write back to the global variable.

IF counter is declared as a local variable, then in fact, using the pointer version would be less optimal. In that case, most compilers would allocate counter into a register, then accessing it would be very fast. If a pointer is used, counter would be forced to be allocated to the stack (since its address is assigned to "p"), and more instructions would be needed to do the addition and access.

Answer (score -2):

it is right opposite (almost identical but one instruction more :):

https://godbolt.org/z/xDYecQ

[image]

Comment: the "extra instruction" is because foo1 updates the global value of `p`  ; both `while` loops compile to the same assembly. I don't think that is what OP is asking about (although the question is not very clear); in OP code `p` was a local variable to the function

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes it's almost identical there is only one less LDR.N
in the code with pointer

Comment: @M.M I know why (did you missed the smiley?)

Comment: @P__J__ I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: @M.M There is no answer. Why is `a` larger than `b`?  But `b` is larger or equal `a` - so how how to answer the initial question

Comment: Why make `int*p` a global?  The OP's code has it as a local.  This introduces a confusing unnecessary difference since your screenshot(!) of the Godbolt compiler explorer hides enough of the source pane that it's not really readable.  Plus, the OP is compiling for ARM with a different compiler in debug mode, and *that*'s the problem.